# AR.JS: Desktop-based static target image

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality, ar.js

I don't need or want "live placement" using a camera. I will already have an image with a target in it, and a second image for which I know its real-world dimensions.  I want to place this second image on top of the image with a target in it, but in the correct position/perspective, etc.  Then save the result as a third combined image.

I can't find any information on how I would implement this with AR.js, or if it is even possible.

Comment: I know AR.js can use a video as input (which can include video with a marker). It may also be able to use an image, but I'm not certain.